# How to use embedsMany in laravel to get all attributes? Only foreign key is returning

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

Hello Good Developers,

I am trying to implement embedsMany relationship of [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

I have two collections:

- ProfileSection - `{
  "_id": "5c865ea4257db43fe4007331",
  "general_name": "MY_PROFILE",
  "type": "public",
  "points": 100,
  "status": 1,
  "translated": [
      {
          "con_lang": "US-EN",
          "country_code": "US",
          "language": "EN",
          "text": "My Profile",
          "description": "My Profile"
      },
      ...
  ],
  "updated_at": "2019-03-11T13:12:04.000Z",
  "created_at": "2019-03-11T13:12:04.000Z"
  }`
- Profile Questions - `{
  "_id": "5c865ea3257db43fe40072b2",
  "id": "STANDARD_EDUCATION",
  "general_name": "STANDARD_EDUCATION",
  "country_code": "US",
  "order": 1,
  "profile_section_id": "5c865ea4257db43fe4007331",
  "profile_section": "My Profile",
  "translated": [
      {
          "con_lang": "US-EN",
          "text": "What is the highest level of education you have completed?",
          "hint": null,
          "mapping": {},
          "answers": [
              {
                  "precode": "1",
                  "text": "3rd Grade or less",
                  "mapping": {}
              }
          ]
      },
      {...}
  ],
  "updated_at": "2019-03-11T13:12:03.000Z",
  "created_at": "2019-03-11T13:12:03.000Z"
  }`

In **ProfileSection** I have added

```
public function questions()  
{  
    return $this->embedsMany(ProfilerQuestions::class, '_id', 'profile_section_id');  
}
```

If I execute `ProfileSection::find('5c865ea4257db43fe4007331')->questions`
It returns me Profile Questions Object with **only one attribute**: `5c865ea4257db43fe4007331` i.e **ObjectId** of **Profile Section**

[image]

I tried using `->with('questions)` before accessing questions object 
like [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/313)
but it's not working

I don't understand what's the issue will definitely need some help.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @amansoni211 unfortunately I don't remember how I solved it